Better syntax highlighting for PostgreSQL in VS Code
This code:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON some.table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION some_trigger_function();

is highlighted like this:

See the yellow instead of blue REPLACE or the white instead of blue FOR EACH? I suppose this is some standard sql syntax highlighting. But for PostgreSQL this is good.
I tried installing extensions like "Better PostgreSQL Syntax" or "PostgreSQL" but nothing changed.
How can I get good syntax highlighting for PostgreSQL in VS code?

Might be worth checking that the filetype is being detected as postgresql rather than generic sql. Beyond that you probably need to contact the syntax highligher projects themselves.

Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly there is no postgresql or pgsql filetype in vs code.

the plugins provide the custom types

That gave me the necessary hint. Thanks a lot! :)

The extension PostgreSQL by Chris Kolkman did the trick for me in the end.
In its feature list under "Programming Languages" there are file extension *.pgsql and *.psql listed.
What I did then:

Disable the extensions Better PostgreSQL Syntax, SQLTools and the dependent PostgreSQL driver
Install PostgreSQL by Chris Kolkman
Rename *.sql files to *.pgsql
Reload the window

After that VS Code recognised the new file extensions and used the correct syntax highlighting (Language Mode "Postgres").

You can also I think just add ".sql" to the list of types it recognizes (if you are only/mostly using PG)

If it is possible to then select which extension is doing the syntax highlighting this could be a solution too. But I don't know (and couldn't find it so far) how I can select the extension that is doing the syntax highlighting.
